# How to pass array of const referenced shared pointer to other function in c++

Tags: c++, function, c++11, shared-ptr

I'd like to pass an array of const referenced shared pointer to another class.

How to use a function parameter for it?

Below is example.

```
// < BaseClass >
 std::shared_pointer<queue> queue_[3];

// init 0,1,2
 queue[0] = std::make_shared<queue>

// move queue to inner class
// Is this right usage?
std::vector<const std::make_shared<queue>&> queue_vector;
queue_vector.emplace_back(queue[0]);
queue_vector.emplace_back(queue[1]);
queue_vector.emplace_back(queue[2]);

 InnerClass.init(queue_vector)
```

```
<InnberClass>
    // I don't know how to use func param
    // this is normal usage to pass shared pointer
    init(const std::shared_pointer<queue>& queue)
    {
      queue_ = queue;
    }
    // array of share pointer(const ref) to func
    init(const std::vector<const std::make_shared<queue>&>& queue_vector)
    {
        queue_array_[0] = queue_vector.at(0);
        queue_array_[1] = queue_vector.at(1);
        queue_array_[2] = queue_vector.at(2);
    }
```

Comment: it depends on what you want to do. Do you want to increase `shared_ptr`'s ref count on `init` (which is the case normally) or not?

Comment: @Afshin No need to increment, just to use const reference.

Comment: There's nothing special about `shared_ptr`, you can pass an array of them like any other structure. You'd be better off using `std::vector` or `std::array` than raw arrays though